# Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'NSURL *'

Tags: ios, objective-c

hi every body ı am working on the block reader application. when ı bug the application

```
       terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

it get the that one error, and in the notification section ı receive the this error

Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'NSURL *'

fot the this codes

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showBlogPost"]){
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    BlogPost *blogPost = [self.blogPost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [segue.destinationViewController setBlogPostURL:blogPost.url];
}
```

}

ı am really dont know why, due to blogPost.url??, but why??
is the any advice??

Comment: Welcome to SO. Since we don't know any of your data types we can't help you debug your program. You need to show the code that populates your arrays, as well as the definition of your `self.blogPost` property and the code that populates it.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray*blogPost; lite that or??

Comment: if NSMutableArray *blogPost is your array so how can you access blogPost.url?

Comment: brother tnx for ur answrs ı find the error and fix. tnx so much

Comment: The exception means that the array `self.blogPost` is empty.  The code asks it for an element, `indexPath.row`, which is equal to zero (there's a good chance indexPath is nil), but the 0th element of an empty array does not exist.

Comment: yes bro u are tottaly right :)) tnx uu so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding the uncaught exception error,

your self.blogPost is empty, when you try to fetch the object at index 1.
so it is unable to set the value of blogpost variable.

```
Try to check if self.blogPost contains data or empty before assigning.
```

regarding NSURL error,
your segue controller destination variable "BlogPostURL" is of NSURL type.
you are trying to set the value of NSString. Try this:

```
[segue.destinationViewController setBlogPostURL:[NSURL URLWithString:blogPost.url]];
```

also, check if you really get the value blogPost.url before calling segue destination controller method.